# Merging two multidimensional arrays while deleting duplicates, relying about a specific element of them

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I was working on `Facebook API`.
I have got this array:

```
["data"] => Array(31) {
    [0] => Array(6) {
        ["id"] => String(13) "6003110325672"
        ["name"] => String(17) "Cristiano Ronaldo"
        ["audience_size"] => Integer  122006620
        ["path"] => Array(3) {
            [0] => String(9) "Interessi"
            [1] => String(20) "Interessi aggiuntivi"
            [2] => String(17) "Cristiano Ronaldo"
        }
        ["description"] => NULL
        ["topic"] => String(6) "People"
    }
    [1] => Array(6) {
        ["id"] => String(13) "6003114817426"
        ["name"] => String(10) "Ronaldinho"
        ["audience_size"] => Integer  17910990
        ["path"] => Array(3) {
            [0] => String(9) "Interessi"
            [1] => String(20) "Interessi aggiuntivi"
            [2] => String(10) "Ronaldinho"
        }
        ["description"] => NULL
        ["topic"] => String(6) "People"
    }
```

which goes on with additional indexes. Then I've got this one:

```
["data"] => Array(45) {
    [0] => Array(11) {
        ["id"] => String(13) "6003129962717"
        ["name"] => String(16) "Zinédine Zidane"
        ["type"] => NULL
        ["path"] => NULL
        ["description"] => NULL
        ["source"] => NULL
        ["partner"] => NULL
        ["audience_size"] => Integer  14137830
        ["country"] => NULL
        ["country_access"] => NULL
        ["topic"] => NULL
    }
    [1] => Array(11) {
        ["id"] => String(13) "6003115921142"
        ["name"] => String(13) "Thierry Henry"
        ["type"] => NULL
        ["path"] => NULL
        ["description"] => NULL
        ["source"] => NULL
        ["partner"] => NULL
        ["audience_size"] => Integer  2601710
        ["country"] => NULL
        ["country_access"] => NULL
        ["topic"] => NULL
    }
    [2] => Array(11) {
        ["id"] => String(13) "6003114817426"
        ["name"] => String(10) "Ronaldinho"
        ["type"] => NULL
        ["path"] => NULL
        ["description"] => NULL
        ["source"] => NULL
        ["partner"] => NULL
        ["audience_size"] => Integer  17910990
        ["country"] => NULL
        ["country_access"] => NULL
        ["topic"] => NULL
    }
```

which as the first one, goes on with additional indexes.

First I tried to merge the arrays using `array_merge()`, but it didn't work, because I lost part of data inside of them. So I'd like to merge them correctly. Then, I noticed that in the second one I have "Ronaldinho" element as a duplicate (`2nd array index 2` and `1st array index 1`). I tried almost everything to figure out how to remove either the first or the second in the merged one, but `PHP` replies me everytime with errors and warnings.

My goal would be having both arrays in one, removing the duplicates, based on the 'name' element.

I thank whoever could help me, i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. One possibility is to use the ids from the first array to filter the second array before merging.

Get the ids:

```
$ids = array_flip(array_column($first, 'id'));
```

Create a filter:

```
$distinct = function($item) use ($ids) { return !isset($ids[$item['id']]); };
```

Filter and merge:

```
$result = array_merge($first, array_filter($second, $distinct));
```